# Change the output to ascending instead of descending order in Python

Tags: python, sorting, web-scraping, python-asyncio, streamlit

I have a function that loops forever and retrives the latest article written from a webpage and parses it on a Streamlit local website. For now the output goes in a descending order and the latest article gets printed last. Is there a way to reverse it, to get the latest on top?

```
import streamlit as st
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

async def main():

    async with websockets.connect(website) as websocket:
        async for message_ in websocket:
            data = json.loads(message_)
            st.write(data)

asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

I have tried to store it inside a list then `.sort()` before parsing it out.

```
list = []

async for message_ in websocket:
   data = json.loads(message_)
   list.append(data)
   list.sort()
   st.write(list)
```

Comment: what does `data` look like? Is it a string, number, object?

Comment: it is a string!

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method is for sorting a list by eg. alphabetical or numeric order. In your case, you just want to reverse the list, so you can use `.reverse()`

```py
list = []

async for message_ in websocket:
   data = json.loads(message_)
   list.append(data)

list.reverse()
st.write(list)
```

Note that I'm only writing the list to the stream at the end, instead of each time.